# Change plotly bar chart x axis from weeks to days

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have a table that I'm currently trying to display on a bar chart. It is annual data, with various data from the 1st/jan of one year until the 31st/dec of the same year

```
    DATE        COUNT
0   2019-01-01      42
1   2019-02-01      3
2   2019-03-01      31
3   2019-04-01      13
4   2019-05-01      1
...
```

When I plot this with 'date' as the x-axis, plotly is automatically converting the x axis to weeks, so that i have 52 bars instead of 365.

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x="DATE", y="COUNT", title="title")
fig.update_layout(bargap=0.30)
fig
```

I've tried updating the ticks with various formats, but this just changes the x axis labels, not the number of bars

I'm not sure how to change it from weekly to daily on the x-axis

Comment: Hi, did you try bar chart? Can you give more information why you use histogram. Histogram automatically select a number of bins if not specified. https://plotly.com/python/reference/histogram/

Comment: ah yes this worked,  thank you! basically i was using histograms because there are other columns in the df and the bars would have a striped look rather than being solid, which histogram fixed. now i have bars for each day but again they have this 'striped' look